# suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: 'Number'

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, suds

I'm using the latest version of suds (https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) for the first time and I'm getting stalled at step one.

```
suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: 'Number'
```

WSDL file here : https://teenused.elion.ee/external/services/index.php?wsdl

I tried to use `ImportDoctor` but it didn't help me.
Do you think about it?

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.sax.text import Raw
from suds.xsd.doctor import Import, ImportDoctor

tns = "http://teenused.elion.ee/external/services/"
imp = Import('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
imp.filter.add(tns)
url = 'https://teenused.elion.ee/external/services/index.php?wsdl'
client = Client(url, plugins=[ImportDoctor(imp)])

raw_request = Raw(***request***)
print client.service.listOwnNumbers(__inject={'msg': raw_request})
```

***request***

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://teenused.elion.ee/external/services/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <wsse:Security mustUnderstand="true">
     <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>P023445433765@elion.ee</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">*********</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">N2Q3YTliYTExMzY2YjQxZTY2YWZjMjY4MWFlYzIxMTY=</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2015-01-20T07:40:47.840077Z</wsu:Created>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
 </SOAP-ENV:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
   <ser:listOwnNumbers/>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: code snippet please?

Comment: @Anmol_uppal I attached code snippet.

Comment: You possibly need to inspect what server responses. Sometimes this error occurs when server send you something in response which undefined in wsdl schema.